# Функция reversed() в Питоне

Tags: python

Если написать вот так.

```
s = 'abc'
print(reversed(s))
```

В ответ получаю - reversed object at 0x003248F0. 
Совместно с join она отрабатывает как и должна.

```
s = 'abc' 
print(''.join(reversed(s)))
```

В ответ - cba.
Так вот вопрос - почему напрямую со строками функция reversed() не работает?

Answer (score 3):

[`reversed()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed) работает с произвольными последовательностями или с объектами с `__reversed__()` методом и всегда возвращает *итератор*, обходя который можно получить элементы входной последовательности в обратном порядке.

Строка является последовательностью и значит `reversed()` может работать с ней. Чтобы получить обратную строку сразу, можно использовать выражение `s[::-1]`:

```
>>> 'abc'[::-1]
'cba'
```

---

Хороший вопрос, почему функция `reversed()` не возвращает строку, если ей на вход дать строку. Например, [`filter()` функция на Питоне 2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) может возвращать разные типы:

```
>>> filter(None, "abc")
'abc'
>>> filter(None, [1,2,3])
[1, 2, 3]
>>> filter(None, (1,2,3))
(1, 2, 3)
```

В Питоне 3, [`filter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) уже возвращает итератор как и `reversed()`:

```
>>> filter(None, "abc")
<filter object at 0x7fe43b586f60>
>>> list(_)
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Возможное объяснение: использование итераторов экономит память (не нужно всю обратную последовательность сразу в памяти держать) и является более общим (нет специальной обработки подклассов встроенных типов таких как `str`, `list`, `tuple`). `reversed()` более поздняя функция (только в Python 2.4 появилась) поэтому её интерфейс более универсальный с акцентом на более экономичную общую и простую реализацию.

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том, что `reversed` возвращает итератор на реверсную строку. Посмотрите в документации: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reversed

Answer (score 1):

@Anton,

Как правильно заметил предыдущий стэковчанин, `reversed()` возвращает итератор, поэтому нужно обёртывать вызов функции в `list()` или `tuple()`.

А теперь практика:

```
s = 'abc'
print(list(reversed(s)))
```

Выводит: `['c', 'b', 'a']`

Итераторы полезны в циклах `for`, генераторах и подобных. Так что при обходе последовательности, например, обёртывать в `list()` ничего не надо.